# Can't get the second last portion of a big string using excel formula

Tags: excel, string, excel-formula

How to split the second last portion of a big string separated by space using excel formula?.

To be specific: if I consider the below string then I wish to get the second last portion of it `TX`.

This is the string I would like to get second last portion from:

`OWNER 915 BROADWAY ST HOUSTON TX 77012-2126`

When I tried with (considering the string is in Range("B1") and I wish to get the last portion in Range("B1"):

`=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))`

I get the result for the last portion of a string:

`77012-2126`

However, when It comes to extract the second last portion I got stuck.

Expected output:

`TX`

Any help on this will be highly appreciated.

Post Script: I'm not after any solution regarding vba.

Comment: Do these strings always have the same format, i.e. ending in a 5 digit ZIP with 4 digit PO box?  Can you show us more data?

Comment: They are not at all identical in length.

Comment: @Jeeped I know that...did you think I did not?  My question was getting at whether every record had the same format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try,

```
=TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", REPT(" ", LEN(A1))),2*LEN(A1)), LEN(A1)))
```

Comment: You are the gem of a guy @Jeeped. It did the trick accurately.

Comment: My goodness!! I don't have much privilege to press another upvote. Turn out that changing the `2` within your formula I can get any portion I want.